# pop up window f3 are open in google chrome but not visible in front

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

hi i am working on a web application using there pop up for search .. but its not working on Google chrome browser what will be reason . its open but not show in front its open on back of the browser .any guys if know the solution please help me i am waiting thanks in advance to all of you. my code is

```
$('#cs_code_nr').jQee('F3', function(e) {
   window.open("search_f3.php?mast_cs_code=mast_cs_code","","width=500,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no");
});
```

if there any confusion please ask me i will describe but please if you know help me

Comment: In what handler is your function? `document.ready` or `window.onload`?

Comment: window.onload function

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle or online link which replicates this issue?

Comment: actually i am using a hot key for search its working properly on other browser but not working on chrome . its open on chrome but only for little seconds and after that hide on browser ...is there any solution

Comment: In chrome, is popup put under opened main window or closed? Again, any online link?!

Comment: its open but not show in front i have to minimize browser for see it.

Comment: Pop up windows went out of fashion in 1999 -perhaps you should try an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of native browser behaviour of pressing F3 which open search box feature on main page, bringing it back focus.

You could try:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    // e.which === 114 for 'F3' on my laptop, could vary maybe
    if(e.which === 114) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Be aware, i'm really not sure it could be your issue here, i don't know this plugin `jQee`.

Comment: thanks for help but its not working . and one thing i want to ask you .. is there any function which can find out the next visit  of user . when a user leave our web site where they go can i find out it. reply

Comment: @user3304880 Until you provide online link, i can only guessing, unfortunately...

Comment: is there any function which can find out the next visit of user . when a user leave our web site where they go can i find out it

Comment: How is it relevant to your opening question??? You should ask a new question regarding this instead. Anyway, the answer is NO, unless user is clicking an anchor on your own page of course. Regarding your current question, even using localhost, why couldn't you set a jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks  actually i find out solution for previous question thanks

Comment: So then please consider to post it as answer, could be usefull for any other person is same situation as you

Comment: actually i have change some browser setting .. i will post when its all working properly ..